# Best way to execute CMD from SQL script

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want to generate some excel reports using vba scripts called from stored procedure. My team got almost the same BI solution, and previously they were using VBA script that opened excel file with macros inside.

Report generation process follows this path:

There's SQL Stored procedure executed from weekly scheduled job, there we call another procedure which is preparing and calculating data, and then we open 
script presented below to run excel.

Here's how this script looks like:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\Path\To\Excel.xlsm")
```

We call this script in such way:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WSCRIPT.EXE Z:\Path\To\Script.vbs'
```

I got some problems with WSCRIPT.EXE, it's hanging when opening reports, and when I was looking for solution I've read much about not using `XP_CMDSHELL`. And the question is: Is there any way to avoid using `XP_CMDSHELL` and to not to create report generation path from scratch? I'm a bit in hurry so I don't have time to write new procedures etc.

Comment: Try using `cscript.exe` instead of `wscript.exe` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490816.aspx. `Wscript` raises errors and messages to the GUI - this might be the cause of the hanging process.

Comment: If it is possible for you to change the `Stored Procedures` to `Table-Valued-Functions` (best was **inline-TVF**), this can be done much easier. You just open an ODBC connection and call directly from SQL Server like `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunction(@prm1,@prm2,...)`. There's even an assistant to help you with *external data*...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to not run script via sql server. The main reasons are security, error handling and easy administration (for example when you want run only one part).

You should try get data from database from your application (in your example it's xlsx file - it's not proble run procedure from sql server programaticaly). If it have to be scheduled than use job agent or task scheduler (one job/task with more parts) or create ssis package or there are metods via linked server/openrowset how to write data into excel directly.

But when you use appropriate error handling it can be in xp_cmdshell too.